# Can't set md5 password in HSQLDB: routine signature not found

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

Documentation on MD5 in HSQLDB is somewhat scarce, but I have followed these instructions to in order to enable md5-ing my passwords:

```
CREATE FUNCTION md5(VARBINARY(128))
RETURNS VARBINARY(226)
LANGUAGE JAVA
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.hsqldb.lib.MD5.digest'
```

Now when I try to update my password:

```
UPDATE worker SET password = md5('pass123') WHERE wid=1
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.MD5(CHARACTER)
```

I'm not that well acquainted with sql, so I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function signature with character strings, rather than binary.

```
CREATE FUNCTION md5(VARCHAR(128), VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
LANGUAGE JAVA
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.hsqldb.lib.MD5.encode'
```

And call the function with a fixed encoding argument:

```
UPDATE worker SET password = md5('pass123', 'ISO-8859-1') WHERE wid=1
```

Comment: @fredt: Is there a general way to access those `org.hsqldb.lib.**` methods through convention from SQL statements?

Comment: You need to create a function before you can call a static method, regardless of the classpath. All public static functions with supported parameter types can be made into a function.